# Poster, tcolorbox, and small math font size

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox, posters

I don't know why, but the math equation looks very small in my tcolorbox poster. Any idea why?

Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To switch to the T1 encoding
% \usepackage{lmodern} % To switch to Latin Modern
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}

\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster,most]{tcolorbox}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {
      spread,
      % interior style={top color=yellow,bottom color=yellow!50!red},
      top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=15mm, right=15mm,
    },
    poster   = {showframe=false,columns=3,rows=5,spacing=13mm},
    boxes    = {
      enhanced standard jigsaw,sharp corners=downhill,
      arc=10mm, boxrule=2mm,
      coltitle=black!85,
      boxsep=0pt,
      top=15mm,bottom=15mm,right=15mm,left=15mm,
      colback=white,opacityback=0.75,colframe=cyan!30!white!90!black,
      title style={left color=cyan!20!white!90!black,
        right color=cyan!20!white!90!black,
      },
      fonttitle=\Large\scshape\bfseries,
      valign=center,
    },
    fontsize = 36pt
    ]

  \posterbox[blankest,interior engine=path,height=10cm,
    halign=center,valign=center,colupper=black,
    ]{name=title,column=1,span=3,below=top}{
    {\Huge\bf\textsc{I Want A Title With\\[.3em]
        Small Caps Enabled}}\\[.3em]
    \textsc{Here are Some Names}
  }

  \posterbox[adjusted title=Security]
  {name=security,below=title,column=2,span=1}{
    I am some text, and here is a formula $hc(x,r) = \sum x_i r_i \bmod 2$, isn't it strange to have such a small formula?
    $$hc(x,r) = \sum x_i r_i \bmod 2$$
  }

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

-- EDIT --
Using `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}` as proposed in comments works indeed (thanks!), but this font is a bit too different from the default one. The lmodern font on the other side gives an ugly sum symbol:

[image]

Comment: The math font you are currently using is not available in the size you want. A quick workaround could be to comment in the `lmodern` and use this for math font

Comment: Personally I would combine palatino with a math font which is a bit heavier, for example `\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{palatino}`

Comment: @samcarter thanks for the comments. if I comment in `lmodern`, the `\sum` symbol looks ugly and really small (less than a letter)

Comment: @samcarter : and the `mathdesign` shape indeed works, thanks! But I'm curious, is there a resizable math font that looks closer to the default one?

Comment: If you want to stay close at the default look, I'd use `lmodern` and fix the sum symbol size with the `exscale` package

Comment: @samcarter great! thank you very much! Feel free to add an answer if you want me to accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the default math font you are using is not available in the size you request it. As a workaround use a math font with is scalable to this size.

If you want to keep the look of the default math font, you could comment in the `lmodern` package you already have in your preamble and fix some remaining problems with the `exscale` package:

```
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{exscale}
```

[image]

Personally I would combine your palatino font with a math font which is a bit heavier

```
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{palatino}
```

[image]

Or use a similar font which also provides math. This will also save you from using the outdated `palatino` package.

```
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the use of `palatino` discouraged (l2tabu)?

Comment: @TeXnician Could very well be. I'll stress more to use `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` instead.

Comment: @TeXnician what's the problem with `palatino`? Not that I'm using it, but I'm curious nonetheless.

Comment: @thymaro Please read the section in l2tabu. I just know that the authors of l2tabu mostly know what they are writing about.

Comment: @TeXnician right. That's actually what I did after posting the comment. I should have done that before, though. I should probably read the whole document again, now that my understanding of TeX has grown. Last time I read it, I didn't quite grasp its reach.